# Android Oreo: Grouped Notifications With Notification Channels

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I followed the documentation provided [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group.html) and can successfully create a notification group on Android N and higher. The issue I'm having however, is with Android Oreo, each notification posted to the group plays the sound for the group.

This is annoying because I'd just like the sound to play once. Each individual notification is a summary of the chats the user hasn't read for each chat room they're in. I need the grouping for when there are multiple chat rooms with unread messages.

There doesn't seem to be a way to set the sound for a notification dynamically, it's limited to channel creation.

I tried following what Dan Lew suggested [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/02/07/correctly-handling-bundled-android-notifications/) but the notification sound plays for each notification still.

My question therefore is, how do you get grouped notification in Android Oreo without having a notification sound play for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd been working for the entire week trying to solve it, but I find the answer shortly after asking on StackOverflow lol.

The answer comes courtesy of Dan Lew again, but I needed to call

```
  notificationBuilder.setGroupAlertBehavior(Notification.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY)
```

on the children notifications.

More detail can be found [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2018/01/22/notifications-in-android-8-1/).